# AngularJS: "isolate scope" or "isolated scope"?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

When defining directives, it is common to give them a scope that is separate and does not prototypically inherit from any parent scopes. I have been confused as to whether the term for this is supposed to be "isolate scope" or "isolated scope".

It seems like the majority of the official AngularJS documentation refers to this as "isolate scope". However, some places in the official docs do call it "isolated scope". When first reading "isolate scope", I thought it was a typo. There are a lot of typos in the official docs, so this seemed like a logical assumption.

Comment: More a English question than angular... Isolate is a verb so saying isolate scope doesn't make a ton of sense but to say that you are isolating the scope or you have isolated the scope would be more appropriate since the act of isolation isn't really what's being talked about but rather the state of it being isolated.

Comment: All that said the original docs used isolate as though it were an adjective describing the scope (noun) so assume they mean a scope which has been isolated.

Comment: According to Merriam Webster, "isolate" can _also_ be an adjective. At least roughly synonymous with "isolated". The pronunciations are subtly different.
http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/isolate

Answer (score 0):

The first time the word is introduced [in the directives guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) it is referred to as **isolate scope** (in bold, actually!):

> What we want to be able to do is separate the scope inside a directive from the scope outside, and then map the outer scope to a directive's inner scope. We can do this by creating what we call an **isolate scope**.

Later in the same document it does refer to this as "isolated scope" in the following context:

> Besides making it possible to bind different data to the scope inside a directive, using an **isolated scope** has another effect.

I would suggest that these are basically synonymous and the primary difference is linguistic. The word `isolate` is a verb (to isolate) while `isolated` is an adjective that expresses a state of being. That is my best theory!

Incidentally, the word "isolated" is only used three times on the directives guide, which to me means the authors probably primarily want to refer to it as an `isolate` scope.